# Android bluetooth socket error

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, backport

I am using backport bluetooth api on android 1.6. I am using Google Bluetooth Chat sample app for testing. The app works fine in normal scenarios.

In a scenario, when I try to connect to paired device which is in off state, I get following error:

```
01-04 09:00:11.629: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(84): onGetRemoteServiceChannelResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed (Host is down)
01-04 09:00:11.729: DEBUG/dalvikvm(128): GC freed 4535 objects / 256008 bytes in 296ms
01-04 09:00:21.880: ERROR/bluetooth_RfcommSocket.cpp(1433): connect error: Host is down (112)
```

But it sets the state as connected. The app is unable to catch the exception.
Why does it happen? Or is it the case with backport api?
Any help is appreciated as I am struggling a lot to get things run fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that this is a defect in api.
Please check this: http://code.google.com/p/backport-android-bluetooth/issues/detail?id=15